# Powershell Add-AdGroupMember adding incorrect value Cross Forest

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to add users from **domain/forest B** to groups in **domain/forest A**

The cmdlets below achieve that goal however the user gets added and only shows their Windows username from Domain B but that makes no sense in terms of identifying the user.

If I use the ADUC GUI and search the remote domain and add the user to the group I get the Full Name and the DN of the user.

I have obfuscated the information from the screenshot but the top arrow shows the user added by the GUI and the bottom one shows the user added by the script.

Is there a way to achieve the GUI result programmatically?

```
$DomainBUser = Get-ADUser "Joe.Bloggs" -Server 10.242.88.3

Add-ADGroupMember -identity DomainAGroup -Members $DomainBUser
```

Image of issue can be seen here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dbf29960-af71-475a-b65c-f76b11980de3/addadgroupmember-cross-forest-issues?forum=winserverpowershell#dbf29960-af71-475a-b65c-f76b11980de3

Comment: I don't think the difference here is due to GUI vs. PowerShell, but rather the fact the the first one ("Andrew ***") seems to be a user from the same forest, whereas the TOY09 user is a foreign user

Comment: Hi Mathias, both are the same user from the foreign forest...

Answer (score 0):

I think if you filter the DistinguishedName on the Variable $DomainUser then it should be able to identify correctly the user in question.

So do the following to $DomainUser

```
$DomainUser = Get-ADUser "Joe.Bloggs" -Server 10.242.88.3 | select-object -expandproperties Distinguishedname
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the feedback, if I try this I get the usual error that the DN "CN=user,OU=blah,DC=blah,etcetc" (Domain B DN) cannot find object under domain.com...

Comment: It only seems to work if I pass the entire get-aduser object to add-adgroupmember, I cant just pass the DN or the UPN